# Error while saving different datatypes to file using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, file-io

I am trying to dump two numpy arrays which are of two different data types uint8 and int32 to a file. I am getting following error:

```
 File "C:\ENV\p34\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1162, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('int32') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

I am using following code to write the file:

```
img.tofile(PATH + "add_info_to_img.dat")

# append array_with_info to the beginning of the file
f_handle = open(PATH + "add_info_to_img.dat", 'a')
np.savetxt(f_handle, array_with_info)
f_handle.close()
```

Data info:

```
img.shape
Out[4]: (921600,)
array_with_info.shape
Out[5]: (5,)
array_with_info.dtype
Out[6]: dtype('int32')
img.dtype
Out[7]: dtype('uint8')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is probably related to your data. I can't reproduce this with dummy data of the same type. So we probably need to know the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your file must be open in binary mode, and you must specify the format.

A simple exemple:

```
a=arange(3)
b=arange(3.)

with open('try.txt','wb') as f:
    savetxt(f,a,'%d')
    savetxt(f,b)

"""    
0
1
2
0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
"""
```

But read that backwards will be difficult.
The best approach is probably here to use `np.savez('try2',a,b)`